# Override listeners in ExtJs 4

Tags: extjs, overriding, listeners

Is it possible to override listeners in ExtJs 4.
My code is like below :

```
Ext.define('app.view.SearchForm', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias : 'widget.searchform',
items: [
   {
     xtype: 'radiogroup',
     id: 'type',
     items: [
      {boxLabel: 'Individual', id: 'ind', name: 'clientType', value: 'x',inputValue: 'x', checked: true},
      {boxLabel: 'Non-Individual', id: 'nind', name: 'clientType', value: 'y', inputValue: 'y'}
    ],
    listeners: {
        change: function( radiogroup, checked ) {
     // event code here
     }
  }
  ]

  });
```

Now how to override the listener in a new js file like below:

```
Ext.define('app.view.newSearchForm',{   
override: 'app.view.SearchForm',
alias: 'widget.newSearchForm'
   // how to override the listener

});
```

Is it possible to override listeners like overriding methods ??

Answer (score 2):

Use like

```
       //your code here
       groupExpand : function(view, node, group, eOpts){
           alert("Expand called by refresh");
       },
       initComponent: function() {
           this.superclass().initComponent.call(this);
           this.on('resize', this.groupExpand);
       }
        //your code
```

over ride initComponent methos to override other methods